# Beginner question: how to start a xml file in terminal for URDF?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following a ROS course on edX and we're now learning about URDF. I believe that I understand the syntax but I don't know how to create a xml file without using the .xml extension.
I tried `vim new_robot.urdf` but that doesn't seem to work.

I am using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356676/beginner-question:-how-to-start-a-xml-file-in-terminal-for-urdf?/) by [MaxM](https://answers.ros.org/users/56385/maxm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is nothing special about the file extension on a Linux system. An XML file is just a text file that by convention has `.xml` at the end, and a URDF is just a text file that happens to contain XML-style code that uses the URDF schema and, by convention, has a `.urdf` at the end. When you are opening the `new_robot.urdf` with `vim` I'm guessing the only part that "doesn't seem to work" is that the syntax highlighting and formatting rules aren't following XML rules because vim can't guess that this `.urdf` file is of XML format. Also note, that you don't *need* to end your URDFs in `.urdf`, but for readers of any package you create it would be good to follow this convention.

My suggestion: whatever editor you're using, figure out how to change the mode to treat URDF files as an XML file. This is easily done in `gedit`, `sublime`, `atom`, `emacs`, etc. If you are set on using vim, maybe read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601099/1082525

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1